# How can I negotiate which post method will be called?

Tags: api, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to implement a Post method with different method signatures. How can I do that, I was trying to do it with MessageBodyReader but it seems to call only one type of post that is ObjectMapper if i have one post method with signature ObjectMapper as param.

```
    @POST
    class SomeResource {
        Response post(ObjectMapper obj){
          ...
        }
       Response post(Document doc) {
          ...
        }
    }
```

Problem is MessageBodyReader is called but the type is always for ObjectMapper. Any idea?

The error i get back is

Bad arguments passed to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod@7408b962 ( javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource@df21c92 )

Comment: Are you trying to support two different documents with the same POST or are you trying to support both JSON and XML content types for the same POST?

Comment: Same work in post with JSON and XML objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have done using two different MessageBodyReaders

```
    Object1MessageReader implements MessageBodyReader<Object1>{
    }

    Object2MessageReader implements MessageBodyReader<Object2>{
    }

    Class MyResource {
            postXML(Object1 obj) {
                    ...
            }

            postJSON(Object2 obj) {
                    ...
            }
    }
```